# \SetBgContents text size

Tags: xetex, fontsize, backgrounds

I was trying to add custom page number style using the background package. 
here is my code

```
\makeatletter
\AddEverypageHook{%
         \SetBgPosition{0.5\textwidth,.05\textheight}
         \SetBgContents{\thepage}
          \bg@material%
          }
\makeatother
```

is there any way to change the size of the text written in              \SetBgContents ??

Comment: Try \SetBgScale{factor}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are typical usages (used at the preamble area) for setting the background material

```
\SetBgPosition{0,-.7\textheight} % position
\SetBgContents{-\thepage-}       % content
\SetBgAngle{0}                   % angle
\SetBgColor{black!40}            % color
\SetBgScale{4}                   % scaling
\SetBgHshift{60}                 % horizontal movement
\SetBgVshift{-5}                 % vertical  movement
\SetBgOpacity{1}                 % Opacity  0<Opacity<1
```

In particular, the `position` is based on TikZ node using at syntax.

{0,0} means upper left corner.

{current page.center} or south, west, north east, etc etc.